# Active Directory: Can Admin user install application under user profile?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I been setting up our user pc for a while.
Before we usually ask user to login and we install the applications for them.

I wondering can we use Active Directory to deploy applications to our users without needing to log in.

Thanks for your helping

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one way you can do it is by using Group Policy Objects to deploy applications to your users with a software installation policy.

This GPO feature allows you to deploy an MSI or MSP package to either users or computers on domain-joined machines. The GPO can be assigned to an OU, a domain, or an Active Directory site. It also provides a way to remove packages that were deployed with the policy.

For more information:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/use-group-policy-to-install-software

Comment: Kep in mind it must be MSI, if so you can also upadte later them over the same GPO due the Software Deployment